# urlencode , urldecode in php for Persian or Arabic language

Tags: php, urlencode, urldecode

I get Categories of news from rss of a site like this :

```
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('http://isna.ir/fa/Sports/feed');
$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $item = array (
        'category' => $node->getElementsByTagName('category')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        );
    array_push($feed, $item);
}

$category = $feed[0]['category'];
```

Now I want to use a function to attribute a number to each category like this :

```
function category_selector($str){
    switch ($str) {
        case 'فوتبال، فوتسال':
            return '1';
            break;
        case 'كشتي، رزمي':
            return '2';
            break;
        case 'جهان ورزش':
            return '3';
            break;
        case 'توپ و تور':
            return '4';
            break;
        case 'ورزش بانوان':
            return '5';
            break;
        case 'علم ورزش':
            return '6';
            break;
        case 'نهادهاي ورزشي و ساير':
            return '7';
            break;
        default:
            return '0';
            break;
    }
}
```

But **category_selector($category)** returns 0 for all of news!
I use function with urlencode too , but it didn't changed anything.

Comment: Check encoding. Is everything in UTF8?

Comment: of course , I use `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` at the beginning of my code.

Comment: What about the rss you load?

Comment: rss has Persian characters, I get rss with that codes I write in question, and the unicode header in in file too!

Answer (score 0):

I understand, simply patch following line before `switch($str)` line

```
mb_internal_encoding("utf-8");
```

I'm using in [city classifieds](http://hotbizzle.com) website, I do not have problem at the moment.

An example your script should be like this

```
function category_selector($str){
mb_internal_encoding("utf-8");
switch ($str) {
    case 'فوتبال، فوتسال':
        return '1';
        break; ...
```

I believe it should work.